# Post and page content not displaying in search results

Tags: theme-development, templates, search, the-content

I am using a content-search.php template part to output my search results. The post/page titles and links to those posts/pages are working correctly, but for some reason the `the_content()` function is not rendering any HTML. I have tested for errors with debugging on, but nothing is displayed.

Here is my content-search.php template code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <header class="entry-header">
    <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="%s" rel="bookmark">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h2>' ); ?>
  </header><!-- .entry-header -->

  <div class="entry-content">
    // No content from posts or pages is displayed using the_content function
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </div><!-- .entry-content -->

  <footer class="entry-footer">
    <?php flagstaffcounty_entry_footer(); ?>
  </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
</article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
```

Here is the search.php template code:

```
get_header(); ?>
<div class="content-and-sidebar">
  <main class="main">
    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
      <?php while ( have_posts() ) :
        the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'search' );
      endwhile;
      the_posts_navigation();
    else :
      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
    endif;
    ?>
  </main><!-- main -->
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
  </aside><!-- aside -->
</div><!-- .content-and-sidebar -->
<?php get_footer();
```

The `the_content` function is working on all other templates on my site.

**Update**

Including offending iframe wrapper filter function for reference.

```
function themename_iframe_wrapper($content) {
  if( is_page() ) {
    $pattern = '~<iframe.*</iframe>~';
    preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches);

    foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
      $wrappedframe = '<div class="iframe-container">' . $match .   '</div>';
      $content = str_replace($match, $wrappedframe, $content);
    }
    return $content;
  }
}
add_filter('the_content', 'themename_iframe_wrapper');
```

Any ideas on what I am missing?

Comment: Are you sure the function is not echoing anything? Have you checked the raw HTML source, in case the content is probably just not visible on screen, e.g. hidden via CSS... But if the function really echo nothing (or an empty string), then you can try deactivating plugins and see if the same issue persists.

Comment: You could also try `echo get_the_content()` instead of `the_content()`.. to confirm the latter is the one not echoing the content - and if so, try searching for `add_filter( 'the_content'`, `add_filter('the_content'`, etc. in your theme functions file.

Comment: and what is in the `none` template? Are you sure it's finding posts? If it isn't displaying anything what HTML is it showing instead? Do you mean that the template displays but `the_content` specifically is blank? Normally if `the_content` displays nothing it's because either the content is blank, or, because you've tried using `the_content` filter incorrectly elsewhere

Comment: @SallyCJ I have found the issue. I wrote a filter to find iframes in `the_content` and wrap them in an `iframe-container` div. This code seems to be conflicting with the output in the search results. I have added it to my original question for reference.

Comment: Yes, it's indeed conflicting - your function is only returning the content when inside the `if` block. So there should always be a `return` line outside the `if` block. (Or move the `return` to outside that block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that your function is only returning the content when `is_page()` is true, which is not on the default search results page, where `is_search()` is true. Likewise, the content would also not be returned on singular post pages and anywhere where `is_page()` is not true.

So remember that a filter callback (like your `themename_iframe_wrapper()` function) must ***always return* the content**, just as with shortcode handler functions.

```php
function themename_iframe_wrapper($content) {
  if( is_page() ) {
    ... your code.
    return $content; // don't just return it here
  }

  return $content; // always return the content
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I made the adjustments and the code is working as expected now.